# Measurable functions on the $\sigma$-algebra generated by semi-open intervals

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory

Let $\mathscr{A}$ be the collection $A_{n} = \{[0,n); n \in \mathbb{Z}_{+} \}$ in $\mathbb{R}$. Furthermore let $\mathscr{F}$ be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathscr{A}$.
I'm trying to describe which this generated $\sigma$-algebra and find which functions $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are $\mathscr{F}$-measurable.

Starting with the first part the sets that makes up $\mathscr{F}$ should be $\mathbb{R},\emptyset$ as well as all the sets of $\mathscr{A}$. We can then prooced to find the rest by taking complements, unions and intersections. This would give us $(-\infty,0), [m,n),[n,n+1)$ and $[n,\infty)$ for $n,m\in \mathbb{Z}_{+}$ and $0\leq m < n$.

The second part has me confused. We have that a function $f$ from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ is $\mathscr{F}$-measurable if the inverse image of any measurable set $B \in \mathscr{F}$ is a measurable set in $\mathscr{F}$. However I am not sure how to proceed. In this case I know that the only $\mathscr{F}$-measurable functions are sums of simple function on the form $f(x) = f_{0} \mathbb{1}_{(-\infty,0)}(x) + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} f_{n} \mathbb{1}_{(n,n+1)}(x)$
Here $f_{i}$ is constant and $\mathbb{1}_{(a,b)}(x)$ in the indicator function on the interval $(a,b)$. I however have no way of convincing me that this is the case.

Is there a general way or algorithm to find which functions are measurable with regards to some $\sigma$-algebra and in particular my $\mathscr{F}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description of elements of $\mathscr{F}$ is incomplete. In fact, $\mathscr{F}$ is generated by the following partition of $\mathbb{R}$: $\{(-\infty, 0)\} \cup \{[n, n + 1)\}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}}$. Let us denote this partition by $P$. As $P$ is countable, $\mathscr{F}$ consists of all unions of elements of $P$. In particular, $\mathscr{F}$ is uncountable, whereas your description only lists countably many elements.

Now, I’m not sure if you want a description of when $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is $(\mathscr{F}, \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}))$-measurable (where $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra - this would be the usual notion of a real-valued function being $\mathscr{F}$-measurable) or if you want a description of when $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is $(\mathscr{F}, \mathscr{F})$-measurable (this seems to be what you wrote down in the question). If it is the first case, noting that all singletons are $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$-measurable tells you that a function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is $(\mathscr{F}, \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}))$-measurable iff it is constant on each element of $P$. (Recall that $P$ is the countable partition that generates $\mathscr{F}$.)

If it is the second case, this is somewhat more complicated to describe. Let $\pi: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{\geq -1}$ be defined by $\pi(r) = -1$ if $r \in (-\infty, 0)$ and $\pi(r) = n$ if $r \in [n, n + 1)$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$. Then $\mathscr{F}$ is the pull back of $\mathbb{P}(\mathbb{Z}_{\geq -1})$ along $\pi$, so $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is $(\mathscr{F}, \mathscr{F})$-measurable iff $\pi \circ f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{\geq -1}$ is $(\mathscr{F}, \mathbb{P}(\mathbb{Z}_{\geq -1}))$-measurable. Now, since singletons in $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq -1}$ are $\mathbb{P}(\mathbb{Z}_{\geq -1})$-measurable, by the same argument as in the first case, we see that $\pi \circ f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{\geq -1}$ is $(\mathscr{F}, \mathbb{P}(\mathbb{Z}_{\geq -1}))$-measurable iff $\pi \circ f$ is constant on each element of $P$. That is, $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is $(\mathscr{F}, \mathscr{F})$-measurable iff $\pi \circ f$ is constant on each element of $P$, or, to put it another way, $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is $(\mathscr{F}, \mathscr{F})$-measurable iff for each $S \in P$, there exists a $T \in P$ s.t. the range of $f|_S$ is contained in $T$.

Comment: Thank you for an excellent answer and for catching my mistake! I think it is the first case that we are working with as the result about functions being measureable if constant rings a bell. Does it in general hold that if a $\sigma$-algebra is countable generated we get these kinds of linear combination of constants and indicators?

Comment: @OrganizerOfVictory No - in fact, the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$ is countably generated (by open intervals with rational endpoints, for example), but functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ certainly do not need to be some kinds of linear combinations of indicator functions to be Borel-measurable.

Comment: @OrganizerOfVictory If your $\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr{F}$ on $X$ happens to be generated by a countable *partition* of $X$, then something like that does hold, and you can prove it using the same method as in my answer. But not all countably generated $\sigma$-algebra has to be generated by a countable partition.